# A simple sorting algorithm

Tags: arrays, matlab, function, sorting, indexing

This is a simple sorting function that I wrote in Matlab:

```
function [matrix] = sorting(matrix)
    for index = 1:length(matrix)-1
        if matrix(index) > matrix(index + 1)
            temp = matrix(index + 1);
            matrix(index + 1) = matrix(index);
            matrix(index) = temp;
        end
    end
    check_sorted(matrix)
end

function [matrix] = check_sorted(matrix)
    count = 0;
    for index = 1:length(matrix)-1
        if matrix(index) < matrix(index + 1)
            count = count + 1;
        end     
    end

    if count+1 < length(matrix)
         sorting(matrix);
    end
end
```

The input for `sorting` function is a 1D array, e.g. [4 3 2 1], and it successfully returns the sorted array [1 2 3 4] for the first time I call it, but then it starts to return unsorted arrays?

Comment: what if you send it [2 4 1 3]?  your sorting works only for the exact case you showed, i.e. the input is a reversely sorted array.

Comment: oh sorry. i didn't realize that check_sorted is a part of your sorting process.

Answer (score 1):

You've got a missing semicolon that is causing the results of each call to `check_sorted` to be displayed, which is confusing things. If you add the semicolon, the output from `sorting` with the array `[2 4 1 3]` suggested in the comments is:

```
>> sorting([2 4 1 3])
ans =

   2   1   3   4
```

Clearly this isn't sorted. The problem is that MATLAB passes function arguments by value, not by reference. Since you're not returning the re-sorted matrix from `check_sorted` or updating the return matrix in `sorting` the original matrix never gets updated. You need to change at least one line in each function (changed lines are commented):

```
function [matrix] = check_sorted(matrix)
    count = 0;
    for index = 1:length(matrix)-1
        if matrix(index) < matrix(index + 1)
            count = count + 1;
        end     
    end

    if count+1 < length(matrix)
         matrix = sorting(matrix);   % change: return re-sorted matrix
    end
end


function [matrix] = sorting(matrix)
    for index = 1:length(matrix)-1
        if matrix(index) > matrix(index + 1)
            temp = matrix(index + 1);
            matrix(index + 1) = matrix(index);
            matrix(index) = temp;
        end
    end
    matrix = check_sorted(matrix);   % change: return checked matrix
end
```

Now the matrix will be updated if it is not sorted on the first (or any subsequent) pass and the fully sorted matrix will be returned by `sorting`.

This is an odd sort of recursion that really isn't necessary. If you change `check_sorted` to return a boolean value, true for sorted, false for not sorted, you can change that recursion to a `while` loop around the `for` loop in `sorting`:

```
function [TF] = check_sorted2(matrix)
    count = 0;
    for index = 1:length(matrix)-1
        if matrix(index) < matrix(index + 1)
            count = count + 1;
        end     
    end

    TF = count+1 == length(matrix);   % TF = true if matrix is sorted
                                      % TF = false otherwise
end


function [matrix] = sorting2(matrix)
   while ~check_sorted2(matrix)   % keep going until matrix is sorted
      for index = 1:length(matrix)-1
         if matrix(index) > matrix(index + 1)
            temp = matrix(index + 1);
            matrix(index + 1) = matrix(index);
            matrix(index) = temp;
         end
      end
   end
end
```

Of course the whole thing can be optimized and vectorized, but this will at least get you going.

Answer (score 0):

i tested your algorithms and it worked. so something else might be wrong. but this algorithm is very very inefficient. you may google sort and pick one that suits you.

if you really want to stick with the algorithm, you could improve it by shortening the two loops. for example, after first call to sorting, for each subsequent call to sorting, you could shorten the loop cycle by 1 because the first call to sorting would put the largest number to the end of the array, the second call would put the second largest to the second from the end, and so on. this is so called bubble sorting.  also in check_sorted, you don't need to go through the entire length of the array to check if the array has been sorted. as soon as you see matrix(index) > matrix(index + 1), you can immediately exit the loop (after you set a flag to indicate the array hasn't been sorted).